# Too Many Elements for Style Sheet, Creating with Jquery Takes Too Long

Tags: html, jquery, css, database

This is more of a general question, but I have a project that involves jquery creating divs and modifying the css of a lot of elements. So let's say there are 300 players, and each player gets 30 different divs created, and each div has 10 different elements to color. So I have an array of 100 team color schemes, which looks something like this:

```
var teams = [{name:'AB1', color1:'#4F2683', color2:'#FFC62F', color3:'#4F2683'}];
```

And the coloring function would look like this:

```
$(teams).each(function(i,v) {
    $('#'+v.teams).find('.playerName').css('color',v.color2);
});
```

Everything works fine. The issue is obviously the loading time since it's doing the css on 90,000 different elements and inserting them into the DOM. So it's a waiting time of a couple minutes (please note that this is basically a one-page offline site, so I'm not thinking about visitors). After the initial load, I can go into the Chrome inspector, copy the generated source code, paste it into Word to re-encode any html entities, and paste it back into the html file. This gets the page to load in a few seconds.

But my question is, is there another way to set this up, like with a database? I can't do a style sheet because that's 30,000 different styles. But how it's set up now is basically a choice between too long to load and too cumbersome to update. I'm not asking for too detailed an answer, just whether there is some framework that can do this. Thank you.

Comment: unclear what a database solves.... Setting colors is taking forever? Or is it you building the DOM?

Comment: 90k elements in the DOM is ***far*** too many. Implement server side paging and/or filtering so you can load a subset of the data at a time.

Comment: Probably be slightly quicker using classes rather than `.css()`.   Not sure why it would be 30000 different styles, in your sample you only have 2 colours, so it's likely there's a lot of repetition.   You could probably also use css *rules* so that you don't even need to change the HTML / addClass.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: envision an image of 500x500 pixels. This will give you 250.000 color options. A single image that size loads quick. Give each team and team member a number (*CSS custom property?*), depicting a pixel `row.column`, maybe an image name when you need more than 250k colors (or go big: 1000x1000px will yield 1M color options). You only have to load the image once and with a bit of JS you can retrieve the colors per team member without a huge list of CSS rules. Also, an image pixel doesn't *have* to depict colors, store any info,  it's just bits and bytes after all.

Comment: It's building the DOM that's taking forever. There's definitely way too many elements, but it's the effect that I was going for (overlays that can be flipped through instantly, like trading cards). I think I would need a program that can convert inline styles to css in a way that gives control of how many levels up to cascade. The element creation would still take some time, but the styling of them would be eliminated. I think that might be the only way to speed things up while keeping the level of detail I want.

Comment: It's unclear the end-goal, but maybe you should consider rendering to a canvas.